# Android write access to SD card

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

I am trying to write to External **secondary** storage (sd card), but it looks like I do not have the permission.

According to Android:

"*Secondary external storage must not be writable by apps, except in package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.*"

So this wont work:

```
try {
    String sdCard = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(sdCard, "test.txt"));
    writer.write("a test");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(e.toString());
    //java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/extSdCard/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 
}
```

I have the permission in AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` wont work since I am trying to write to removable sd card not the phone memory.

So, if apps supposed to be prohibited to write to secondary storage, how can apps like [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm) write to sd cards?

Comment: I believe you can't do what you're trying to achieve starting from or only in KitKat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So this wont work:

Among other reasons, I am not aware of a requirement for devices to have a `SECONDARY_STORAGE` environment variable.

> I have the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

That is for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> how can apps like File Manager write to sd cards?

They are relying on users helping them via [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).